# Determining the shunt resistance for DRV8301 BLDC Gate Driver

Tags: operational-amplifier, power-electronics, brushless-dc-motor, gate-driving, shunt

I am trying to study how to drive BLDC (Brushless DC) motors, and got stuck in the current-sensing part.

I am using a DRV8301 Gate Driver IC, which contains with shunt amplifiers. My current understanding is that, knowing the voltage drop and gain used, I can calculate the current if the resistance of the shunt resistor is known. But I can't seem to find this info on its [data sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8301.pdf?ts=1605424976272).

Am I expected to calculate this resistance myself? If so, how should I go about doing that?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Figure out the expected current range and the allowable voltage drop across the resistor...

Comment: Table 14 of data sheet.

Comment: @Andyaka, table 14 is a block diagram where I think R-ISENSE is the resistance I am looking for, but I can't seem to find the value for that.

Comment: Read **TABLE 14**. Or ctrl-F then type Rsense then search

Comment: Thanks! But that value is only an example application. It turns out the resistor is not included in the DRV8301 -- it needs to be provided by the user.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that the sense resistor needs to be provided by the user, and is not included in the DRV8301 itself. It's the resistor placed between SNx and SPx.